# Can't automate R script because it needs to be run in RStudio

Tags: r, windows, rstudio, scheduled-tasks

I have an R script that uses ggplot2 to generate 70+ images and export them to a folder. Unfortunately, when I attempt to schedule the task in Windows (using package taskscheduleR), it fails with the following in the log:

`null device 
          1 
Error in matrix(if (is.null(value)) logical() else value, nrow = nr, dimnames = list(rn,  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
Calls: [<- -> [<-.data.frame -> Ops.data.frame -> matrix
Execution halted`

The script runs perfectly fine when I open RStudio and run it. Here is the R code that exports an image (it appears this is where it's failing):

```
chartpath <- "PATH"
png(filename = chartpath, width = 9.6, height = 7.1, units = 'in', res = 750)
plot(chart)
dev.off()
```

It's also possible (based on my research) that the problem is that the base R files don't have the same packages as RStudio. I don't know how to check that, or how to fix the problem if that's the case.

Does anybody know if there is a workaround where I can just schedule a task to open RStudio and run it? If not, does anybody have any idea what might be going wrong.

Comment: are you using the same file paths for both? when you open rstudio, it will change your working directory to a project-specific or default directory

Comment: Yep. I have code that sets the working data explicitly. This actually broke the automation at first, but I fixed it.

Comment: The code you show doesn't use any non-base packages, so that's unlikely to be the issue.

Comment: It's possible that you don't have the same packages installed in your default RSTUDIO environment, compared to the environment in which your Rscripts run from the command line. Run: `Sys.getenv()` in both locations. You will see a path associated with `R_HOME` which should contain libraries (packages) that you've installed. When you load a library from either environment, it searches in these different locations, and if you've never installed the same packages in each environment, they may not be found.

Comment: So when I run it in RStudio, I get the following path:  C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1 ... In R, I get the same. Is that illustrative of the fact that the packages aren't the issue? @Dij

Comment: Maybe. When you say "run in RStudio" do you mean you are using `knitr::render...` (by pressing Knit). if so, then the scripts may be running in yet another environment. Either way that would be solved by adding `library("package")` to your Rscript, and if you don't get an error there, then it's not the problem (unless you have different version of the packages in each location).

Comment: the error message though makes it appear that you are just getting an error running `matrix()`...

Comment: The problem seems to be in the graphics device. If you are using `ggplot2` start using `ggsave`. Storing your plot into a variable and using `ggsave(file, plot_variable, width = , height =  units = )` should hopefuly fix this problem.

Comment: I think that is the case. I can run the code without issue if I open R.exe instead of Rscript.exe. It sends some images to the graphics though, so I think the Rscript is brekaing at that point. @Oliver

Comment: Have you tried execute the `r script` from a `batch` file?

Comment: Create a script that contains `cat(.libPaths())` and run it using Rscript. That will show you the libraries (folders where packages are stored) that Rscript knows about. Compare to running the same command in R or RStudio.